# How to reload tableview after submission of a page of type present modally in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a post a review system in my app. a user clicks on the review button from the reviewTableViewController and a present modally page pops up that is a postReviewController and he can post a review. after the user clicks the send button, I made it that the present modally page dismisses, but now the post that the user has just written is not shown until I exit the reviewTableViewController and open it again.

how can I reload the table view after dismissing the present modally page?

i tried the unwind method on the click of my reviewBtn, but that cancels all the code that i need it to be executed.

my code:

```
@IBAction func ReviewBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        
       
        
        
        db.collection("Reviews").addDocument(data:[
            //my code here
        ]){ err in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error writing document: \(err)")
            } else {
                
   let messageVC = UIAlertController(title: 
  "Review submitted successfully!", message: "" , preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
                self.present(messageVC, animated: true) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                        messageVC.dismiss(animated: true) {
                            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                            
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                   
                }
              
                
                
            }
            
        }
```

any help or suggestions on this?

Comment: why don't you use the completion closure to reload the tableview. Is not clear in your question the flow to update the data,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a protocol and an object of the protocol in your presented controller as follows

```
 protocol DismissView{
       func updateTblData()
 }

var delegate: DismissView?
```

When you dismiss the view call the method of the delegate as follows:

```
if let delegate = delegate {
    delegate.updateTblData()
}
```

Now in your controller from where you presented the screen, please conform to the protocol and provide definition of the method.

Also when presenting the controller please assign the delegate to self as below:

```
secondController.delegate = self
```

The screen from which you present could look something like below:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController , DismissView {
    @IBOutlet weak var tbl: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {
        let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "new") as! NewViewController
        controller.delegate = self
        present(controller, animated: true)
    }
    func test() {
        
        tbl.updateTblData()
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but what is the func updateTblData()? and what do i code inside it?

Comment: also how would i conform to the protocol, sorry but i am very new to swift programming, and these concepts are new to me.

Comment: Suppose you have this action from where you go to the next screen, this is how you can say that this in the controller where the method implementation will be given :  

@IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {
        let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "new") as! NewViewController
        controller.delegate = self
        present(controller, animated: true)
    }

And to conform you have to 

class FirstController: UIViewController , DismissView {} 

And then give an implementation

 func updateTblData() {
        tbl.reloadData()
    }

Comment: thank you very much, it works perfectly. i am new to swift and your help is greatly appreciated and made me understand swift a little bit better now. and this will help me in the future to complete my app. thank you again for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 2 ways in which you could do this.

1. Using a delegate: The idea is that your `PostReviewController` should call a method in your `ReviewTableViewController` instead of just dismissing itself. And in that case your `ReviewTableViewController` instance would dismiss the `PostReviewController` controller and call reloadData in the completion of the dismiss call. (just search for delegate in swift and you should find a lot of solution which will help you figure it out.
2. Using closures: basically you can pass a closure from `ReviewTableViewController` to your `PostReviewController`. In that closure you will call dismiss and reloadData in completion and your `PostReviewController` instance will call that closure instead of dismissing itself.

P.S. check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss) of dismiss(animated:completion:). Ideally the presenting view controller should be responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented

Comment: thank you for your answer, i am new to swift programming if you could provide me with some details i would appreciate it. thank you again